# How many unique six-digit odd numbers can be formed by the digits $1, 1, 2, 3, 3$, and $3$?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This is the 14th question on the 2018 Blaine WSMC. I tried but just can't figure out the answer since probability is my weak spot, can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I could enumerate quite a few such numbers, but upon inspection none of them turned out to be unique. So I guess the answer must be $0$. Also please be aware that s six-digit odd number is not the same as a six-odd digit number.

Comment: It often helps to start by finding a few solutions "by hand" and then trying to count patterns of the solutions.  In any case sharing your thoughts, rather than pleading "I... just can't figure out the answer", will improve your prospects of getting responses suited to your level of study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either 1 is the units digit or 3 is. If 1 is the units digit, I can place the other 1 in any of the five remaining places, then the 2 in the remaining four, after which the rest must be filled with 3's. This gives $5×4=20$ ways.

If 3 is the units digit, I can place the 1's in $\binom52=10$ ways and the 2 in 3 ways after that, after which the rest must be filled with 3's. This gives $10×3=30$ ways.

Adding the two sub-results gives the final answer of 50 numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: There are $6!=720$ permutations of the digits, not taking account of the fact that some of them are identical. We must divide by $2!=2$ because swapping the 1s makes no difference, and divide by $3!=6$ because permuting the 3s makes no difference. This yields $720/2/6=60$. But we must count only odd numbers. One of these numbers is odd iff the 2 is not in the last position. The 2 appears in each of the 6 positions in $60/6=10$ of these numbers, so 10 of these numbers are even. We must exclude those 10, leaving $60-10=50$ even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You must exclude the uniqueness condition, since it is meaningless.

You've got $\binom6{2,1,3}=60$ different such numbers without the oddness condition. Of those, $1$ in $6$  has the $2$ at the end and is therefore even (you can group the numbers by cyclic permutations if you want proof). So there are $\frac56\times60=50$ odd such numbers (odd positive integers whose decimal representation has two occurrences of the digit$~1$, one occurrence of the digit$~2$, three occurrences of the digit$~3$, and no other digits).